# Using regular expressions in elasticsearch term queries

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I want find all items filtered by ID match some regular expression like

```
*TEST123*   //pattern for regexp
```

So expected result are items

ATEST123001

ATEST123002

ATEST123003

TTTTEST123001

...

I can create some script which scan full storage and save IDs in log-file which can check later. But I want to find some better solution

**Updated**
I tried

```
"query" : { "match_all" : { }, "filtered" : { "filter" : { "regexp": { "id":".test123." } } } }, }
```

I receive

//nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but got START_OBJECT \"filtered\"]

When I tried

```
{
  "regexp": {
    "id": "test123"
  }
```

}

//Parse Failure [No parser for element [regexp]]]

ES 1.7.4 and Lucene 4.10.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Query String](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).

```
{
"query": {
 "query_string": {
    "default_field": "if",
    "query": "*test123*"
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression queries. The regexp query allows you to use regular expression term queries.

Ref:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html

Sample regex query :

```
{
    "regexp":{
        "id": "*test123*"
    }
}
```

Update:
In 2.0 regexp filter has been replaced by regexp query.

```
   {
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "filter": {
            "regexp":{
              "id":".*TEST123.*"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I have tested this type of example but I receive Parse Failure [No parser for element [regexp]]]; }]",

I'm using ES 1.7.4 and Lucene 4.10.4

Comment: ES 1.7.4 and Lucene 4.10.4

Comment: Updated the answer for your version. If still not working, update your question with what you have tried.

Comment: I removed comma before running request. I'm testing at Marvel/Sense - it is autoformat before running. So it is not correct answer

Comment: I have tried it locally and it is working perfectly fine.  Your regex is also wrong. it should be ".*TEST123.*"